# How can I see the console.logs of an external JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, scripting

I'm trying to debug a javascript function. The function is called from an HTML page, which calls a javascript.js src. The source file is on the same server and same directory level, but when I access the HTML page, I can't see the console.logs run inside the javascript file from my browser console.

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this that I'm missing. Outside of pasting the enter javascript code in the HTML file, is there an easy way to monitor console.logs run in an external js script?

Comment: I think we'll need to see your code. It shouldn't matter where you're loading the JS from - if the browser is able to execute it then you should be seeing the logs, assuming you're logging correctly.

Comment: maybe you have active filter in browser console (which hide log messages)?